# Detect screen touching on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, touch, screen, touchscreen

I am trying to develop simple program on single-computer-board with touchscreen. Program will play some videos and when someone touch screen program will close wideos and do another business.

How I can detect screen is touched?

OS is Debian with Wayland.

This is simple code and I have no idea what do next:

```
/**
 * Detect touch event.
 *
 * @param  Buffer|string|any chunk
 * @return Boolean
 */
function thisIsTouchEvent(chunk){
    // let res = ...
    return Boolean(res);
}

/**
 * Initialize touch event.
 *
 * @param  callable callback
 * @return void
 */
function onTouch(callback){
    process.stdin.on('data', (chunk)=>{
        if(thisIsTouchEvent(chunk)){
            callback(chunk);
        }
    })
}

// New touch event
onTouch((data)=>{
    // some magic with data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) to build your application and to facilitate hardware's interactions.

Comment: Electron is great platform but is too big (*complied is up to 200Mb, yes?*) for such simple action...

Comment: You are right, electron is heavy. But 200Mb is too much, tuning electron builder you can optimize the build size to around 60Mb (if you don't include heavy dependencies). The real problem is the memory (RAM) usage. Moreover, i was suggesting you to use Electron for the entire application, not just for the touch event. How is your application built actually? You are you using node js but what about the UI?

Comment: This is device with 500Mb HDD :) Application just showing video with animated logo and when someone touch screen video is turned off and turning on "YOU ARE HERE" image.

Comment: ok Electron can't be a solution. Anyway, as I already asked before, how did u implemented the application? You basically writed a node JS script that execute an installed video player?